# Getting object hash code instead of object value in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashcode

I have a "Student" ArrayList with few objects and I wanted to convert my student ArrayList to string ArrayList but instead of getting the student object value in string ArrayList, I am getting student object hash code like "Student@6acbcfc0".I have a toString() method inside the classroom class. Ignore other kinds of errors. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Classroom{

    List<Student> participants=new ArrayList<Student>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String results = "";

        for(Student d : participants) {

            results += d.toString(); 
    }
    return results;
  }

public String getParticipantsEmail(){
        
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < participants.size(); i++) {

            str.add(participants.get(i).toString());
            
            System.out.println(str.get(i));
        }
```

Comment: Define a `toString()` method in your `Student` class as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see implementation of `Student.toString()`. Do you have such?

`participants.get(i).toString()` calls `Student.toString()`, not `Classroom.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a toString() Method in your Student class

And then simply call

```
System.out.println(student.get(i).toString());
```